# VBA Excel Turning off Grayscale in Word Doc

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have been having an issue with an Excel Application controlling Word documents. Basically the Excel auto fills a Word Doc and prints it on a network printer of your choice. The issue is I need the Word Doc to be printed in colour and I can't seem to turn off the Grayscale option when printing. The Grayscale option is a print option in the print properties menu. I have tried .BlackAndWhite = false but with no luck.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://www.gmayor.com/fax_from_word.htm) will help.

Comment: I had a look and tried SetColorMode = 2 but it didn't work. Thanks for your help though with looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `.BlackAndWhite = False` doesn't change your output, it's most likely that the printer is set to B&W through the printer options. These are outside Excel and cannot be controlled via Excel VBA.

You must go directly into the Printing Preferences dialog for your printer from the OS level (Devices and Printers / [right click printer] / Printing preferences) and turn on color mode. Then in Excel you can select B&W or color

Comment: This is what I thought, I have found a work around in getting the Word Doc to display and manually printing after taking the Grayscale off. Thanks for your help in looking into this for me.

Comment: If you follow the link from @Portland Runner's 2nd comment, you'll find another one which sends you to http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/Pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=183. In there it is explained rather well how to work directly with the Printer API. If you don't mind doing the efforts, this is the way to go

Comment: Excellent, thanks to both of you. I will have a look into it now. If I manage to get anything working I'll post it back up.